# Adding Javascript and SCSS files to wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sass

I have created a plugin for a booking process but I'm not able to add the style or JS files I have been using with it.

CSS file is found at *"css/style.css"* and JS file is found at *"js/script.js"*.

My plugin PHP file which is working is:

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

function sc_booking_process() {

    return 'html code...';
}
add_shortcode('cinema-booking', 'sc_booking_process');
?>
```

It just isn't working with the style and js files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding wp_enqueue_scripts in your plugin file?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_scripts/

```
<?php
function my_scripts_and_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-css', 'css/style.css'  );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-js', 'js/script.js', array('jquery'), '20200110' );       
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_and_css' );
?>
```

Update the files path if you need

Comment: I have tried this. By putting it between ```defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;``` and ```function sc_booking_process() {``` but it still isn't appearing.

Comment: are you sure you add the correct path? thats the code I always use and it works for me

Comment: Yeah I have a folder called css and style.css is in that. Same with script.js it is in the JS folder.

Comment: Should this be put into the same file as the code in my question? I have tried this and it doesn't work even though the file path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
public function enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/syner-public.css', array(), $this->version, 'all' );
}

public function enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/syner-public.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );
}
```

Comment: Would this be in the same file as the plugin code above? If so this doesn't work for me